# Comma in array is used as a value. Array in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cookies, escaping

`($.cookie('cIDlist")` is an array that looks like: `2, 0, 1, 2, 4`.

The function works as intented but somehow the function `imageToSlotNr()` uses both the integer numbers and the commas as values. How do I get it to ignore the separating or commas or just remove the commas? And why is this even happening?

```
$("#vkorzinu").click(function(){
    SLOTNUM = 1;
    $.each($.cookie('cIDlist'), function(){
        imageToSlotNr(this);
        SLOTNUM++;
    });
});

function imageToSlotNr(idnum){
  if(SLOTNUM<9){
  $("#slot"+SLOTNUM).css({"backgroundImage":"url('http://localhost/musli/"+idnum+"ingrid.png'    )","background-size":"70px"});
  } else {
       alert("full");
}};
```

Comment: Where is `imageToSlotNr` defined?

Comment: Then it's a `string`, not an Array.

Comment: Yeah, we have nothing to go on unless you provide the definition of `imageToSlotNr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$.each` is iterating over the characters in a string.

You need to convert to an Array before iterating. Parsing it as JSON can be useful here.

```
var arr = $.parseJSON("[" + $.cookie('cIDlist') + "]");

$.each(arr, function(){
    imageToSlotNr(this);
    SLOTNUM++;
});
```

If you want the numbers as strings, you can use `.split()` instead of parsing it as JSON data.

```
var arr = $.cookie('cIDlist').split(/\s*,\s*/);

$.each(arr, function(){
    imageToSlotNr(this);
    SLOTNUM++;
});
```